# access foreign key via a manytomany relationship in django

Tags: django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a foreign key that is in turn a many to many relation like the following:

Persons<-M2M->Role(ManyToOne)->Name

The model:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    mail=models.EmailField()
    firstName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phoneNumber=PhoneNumberField()
    streetAdress=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zipcode=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Göteborg")
    country=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Sweden")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.firstName,self.lastName)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('firstName','lastName')

class Role(models.Model):

    role=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    person=models.ManyToManyField(Person)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('role',)

class Name(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role=models.ForeignKey(Role,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Address(models.Model):
```

I can acces the manyTomany field from persons and roles but I cannot access names.

the template:

```
{% extends "artdb/base.html" %}

{% block content1 %}
    <ul>
        {% for p in ans %}
    <h5>First name: {{p.firstName}}</h5>
    <h5>Last name: {{p.lastName}}</h5>
    <h5>Phone: {{p.phoneNumber}}</h5>
    <h5>Adress: {{p.streetAdress}}</h5>
    <h5>Zip Code: {{p.zipcode}}</h5>
    <h5>City: {{p.city}}</h5>
    <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock content1 %}

{% block content2 %}
    <ul>
      {% for p in ans %}
           {% for r in p.role_set.all %}
              <h5>{{ r.role }}</h5>
           {% endfor %}       
      {% endfor %}
    <hr>
    </ul>
{% endblock content2 %}

{% block content3 %}
    <ul>
      {% for p in ans %}
           {% for r in p.role_set.all %}
              <h5>{{ r.name }}</h5>
           {% endfor %}       
      {% endfor %}
    <hr>
    </ul>
{% endblock content3 %
```

I konow that I have to iterate to get manyTomany, but is it the same with oneTomany?
how do I access Names from Persons via Role?

}

Comment: But it's just the same, surely? You iterate through the role_set to get reach role, so for each role you have to iterate through the name_set to get each name, no?

Comment: no, <h5>{{r.role_set.all}}</h5> gives nothing.

Comment: No, it's `name_set`, not `role_set`. `r` is already a Role, and has a reverse relation to Name.

Comment: ok, you are right, now it works

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for those interested. (thanks daniel roseman). Iterate through every relation. Here the first relation is many to many and the second many to one:

```
{% block content3 %}
    <ul>
      {% for p in ans %}
         {% for r in p.role_set.all %}
              {% for n in r.name_set.all %}
                 <h5>{{ n }}</h5>
              {% endfor %}      
           {% endfor %}       
      {% endfor %}
    <hr>
    </ul>
{% endblock content3 %}
```